# Creating a PartialViewResult from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have an action method from which I need to return HTML that I obtain from an external URL, and am using the following code to achieve this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
private ActionResult ExternalFoo()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/page.html");
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    return Content(stream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

The response from this action method is embedded in a view, thus:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ExternalFoo", "Controller"); }
```

So it would be more appropriate for the action method to return a [`PartialViewResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Is there a method similar to [`Controller.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470588%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) (used above, which returns a `ContentResult`) that will return a `PartialViewResult` when given a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's anything OOTB for this but my immediate thought is to return an `MvcHtmlString` and render this in a partial view. Something like (untested):

```
var model = new MvcHtmlString(myString);
return PartialView("RawHtml", model);
```

RawHtml.cshtml:

```
@model MvcHtmlString

@Model
```

Not sure if the view engine will like `@Model` like that - you might need to wrap it in something or do some escaping.

Comment: Not sure what difference that makes - you can use strongly typed partials in layouts. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought of this too, but it seems to overly complex. Why have a complete cshtml that just returns the string?!